# IBM UCD - Directory Offset

Tags: urbancode

I am using IBM UCD and configure the directory offset of the `step` `download artifacts`

if the working directory is `C:/program files/agents/workspace/dir1`

`../../../` will work

but  `../../../../F:/dir2` will cause errors.
I am pretty sure that the path `F:/dir2` is legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just the absolute path to the other drive? You should not need to use a relative path to get to another drive. That's overhead you don't need.